# Make Spring registration of @Controller dynamic, without restarting an application server

Tags: java, spring

My application works using an Engine-application, Engine. This Engine allows to reload java classes from my project without stopping an application server (Tomcat) i.e, when I have a new version of my project I deploy it and "call" Engine to reload my code.

The Engine has a registered `DispatcherServlet` (Spring) in `web.xml`, and it is mapped on `/rest/*`. Because of the Engine allows to reload java code without stopping the application server theoretically I can create a `@Controller` class, and Engine will see it. But `DispatcherServlet` will not because it has already been initialized once when application server was run. So, I need, in some way, reinitialize DispatcherServlet with a new set of `@Controller`-s.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

As there could be additional dependencies of your `@Controller` (e.g. other beans, properties, etc) reloading might not be a straightforward task. You can try using [JRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) [which has Spring integration](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/learn/jrebel-spring-integration/). Long time ago there was [Spring OSGI](https://docs.spring.io/spring-osgi/docs/current/reference/html/) project but it's no longer maintained, looks like Pivotal gave up on OSGI.

I always found these technologies not worth their time, hot swapping code in Tomcat always resulted in some kind of leaks or unpredictable behavior. If I were in your shoes I'd optimize the application startup time instead and forget about hot swapping complex Spring beans.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not optimize the startup time because the Engine is a third part product and I can do nothing and even start to use another engine.